# Spanish long distance speed skater in the 1980s?

Tags: speed-skating

We were talking about long distance speed skating recently, and I remember that in the 1980s there was a male Spanish speed skater participating at the World Championships (I don't think he participated in any Olympics). He was a lot slower than the others, but was the first representative of Spain to ever participate.

I've been trying to Google his name, look at the Wikipedia page about Spanish speed skaters (it's not Asier Peña Iturria), but I can't find anything about him. Does anyone remember this guy?

Comment: I see why you did not find him. The list on the English language Wikipedia contains only one name. Dutch version has 4 names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search for EC 1980 gives me: [Antonio Gomez](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_G%C3%B3mez_Fernandez), sorry only available in Dutch and Norsk on Wikipedia.
Yes, that rings a bell. It took him about three years to learn a proper (step-over) turn. Here's his list of records: [Antonio's best](http://www.speedskatingbase.eu/?section=main&subsection=skater&id=6634)

Comment: That's him! We used to make jokes that if he qualified for the 10km, he'd have to turn the lights off on the track...